# What technique should I apply in creating articles in ASP.Net app

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I am in search of a good workable and standard technique to use in creating articles for blog in asp.net. I can create articles by saving all content to SQL server database but i don't know if it will be SEO friendly and also it will grow the size of the database.

Should i create new .aspx page for each article? (updating will be difficult)
I need a good option, any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want to create your own CMS (Content Management System) - some way of entering content in an 'admin' page, saving it to a database and then displaying it in your front-end website; is that right ? How much experience of ASP.NET do you have ?

Comment: If i get a guidline i can work with it perfectly - Just give a suggestion pls

Comment: I have adapted a technique i found in Mad Kristensen BlogEngine app, the articles are saved in a new xml file and the structure is organized in xml nodes. Works perfect and i have used it in lots of website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well; creating a CMS is quite time-consuming. I've built a couple of .NET CMS's (and used several) and I can tell you, it's a lot of work to make something usable.

You could instead try using an existing free CMS (this would be my recommendation): -

http://www.orchardproject.net/

Or you could try create one yourself: -

- Create database table(s) designed to hold different types of content, i.e. BlogPost, Product, DynamicPage, etc
- Make sure these tables have the kinds of fields you'll need to create content from: -

> - Title
> - MetaKeywords
> - MetaDescription
> - Precis
> - Content (make this big, like NVARCHAR(MAX))

- Create admin pages that allow an admin user to create, update and delete items in these tables. You could use a WYSiWYG editor such as TinyMCE for the content. For example, your admin pages might be: -

> ```
>  - Blog List
>  - Blog Add/Edit
>  - Product List
>  - Product Add/Edit
> ```

- Create front-end templates for these tables designed to display their content. These would be along the same lines as the admin pages, except you're displaying them in your public site, not your admin pages, so their page template names might be: -

> - Blogs.aspx
> - Blog.aspx
> - Products.aspx
> - Product.aspx

- Figure out how to render menus and a footer from the same content

Sorry if that sounds a bit vague; your content requirements will probably be different and as I said, *making* a CMS can be quite a lot of work.

You could also try googling: -

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/10041/creating-cms-with-aspnet

Hope that helps friend

Comment: Thanks alot, at least i have seen a guideline needed.. Hopefully, am gonna make something out of